# Animation affecting y-scroll length

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, animation

I am currently using this animation library: https://daniel-lundin.github.io/react-dom-confetti/. Every time I fire my confetti the Y Scroll will increase until the confetti animation is over.
I was just wondering if theres a way to lock y-scroll to a maximum height.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide some of your code, please?

Comment: literally the same as the link I provided. Once you click 'Hit Me' the confetti animation will occur and the Y scroll would extend. Thanks for your help!

Comment: From the help section: _"If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to then do so - but also copy the code into the question itself"_ This might help you get some answers, because it's actually easier to answer when the code is right there, and it lets us copy it into our answers. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could add a **listener** to your button and add a **class** while the animation is running.

```
document.querySelector('.app__confetti button').addEventListener('click', event => { document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden' })
```

You could listen to **transitionend** or maybe use **mutation observer**.

I tested that in my browser and it removes the `overflow-y`.